# How to find a query that you can find with FASTA but not with BLAST and vice versa?

Tags: sequence, bioinformatics, fasta, blast

I need to find a sequence or sequences that should give results (hits) in Fasta but not in Blast, or vice versa.

And I am kinda lost.

What should I look for while searching this sequence(s)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? FASTA and BLAST are completely different things; BLAST is a search while FASTA is a format.  FASTA can't find things.

Comment: @iayork oh you youngin's FASTA was originally an alignment program that predates blast.  the only thing we still use from it was the file format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/116280/

Comment: I need to find a dna or protein sequence (query) that can't give any results by using Blast. At the same time, it should give result when i put it into FASTA tool.

What can i look for?

Answer (score 0):

When you say find a sequence by BLAST or FASTA I assume you mean find a hit in the database?

I think FASTA might be better at finding alignments between dissimilar sequences than BLAST but BLAST is better at aligning similar sequences.

Comment: What do you mean by dissimilar sequences?

Comment: @HiloKub sequences with a low percent identity.

Comment: So you are saying i need to choose discontiguous megablast option, am i right?

But i need to write something to query also (which i have no idea now because blast gives hits with anything i write down)