# How to find a sequence that can't give any results by Blast, but give by FASTA?

Tags: bioinformatics, similarity, fasta, dna-sequence, blast

I need to find a dna or protein sequence (query) that can't give any results by using Blast. At the same time, it should give result when i put it into FASTA tool.

What can i look for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26491285/1030675

Answer (score 0):

The FASTA tool is put out by EMBL-EBI http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/sss/fasta/ and uses the UniProt databases. The BLAST tool by NCBI uses a number of databases listed [here](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=ProgSelectionGuide). While UniProt is reputed to be 'the universal protein resource, a central repository of protein data' (see the Wikipedia entry) created by combining the Swiss-Prot, TrEMBL and PIR-PSD databases. From the BLAST site, it appears that the TrEMBL database is not included in their repository, so I would look for sequences which have been loaded into TrEMBL and not in the other databases.